# Generate AWS S3 presigned URL using python that forces objects to be downloaded

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am able to use python to generate presigned URLs to AWS S3 objects using the code [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html). When I use the generated URL, some objects open in the browser and some are downloaded. Can I force the URL to download the object? I have read that the Content-Disposition header can be used to accomplish this, but I cant seem to find an example using python.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be a standard practice

```
def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):
try:
    response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
        "get_object",
        Params={"Bucket": bucket_name, "Key": object_name},
        ExpiresIn=expiration,
    )
except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
    return None

return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Mobasshir's answer didn't do it for me. Instead, this worked for me:

```
def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=10):
    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            'get_object',
            Params={
                'Bucket': bucket_name,
                'Key': object_name,
                'ResponseContentType': 'binary/octet-stream' # this is the crucial line
                    },
            ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None
    return response
```

I am using Python 3.10.4 with AWS boto3 1.21.24.